# Counter doesn't change its state

Tags: flutter, dart

So I am trying to make counter in my cart ui that will help me update the quantity of item.

```
          CounterCustom(
            initialValue: _defaultValue,
            minValue: 0,
            maxValue: 10,
            step: 0.5,
            decimalPlaces: 1,
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                _defaultValue = value;
                _counter = value;
              });
            },
          ),
```

This is the counter package I am using. If I place this widget in ListView directly under my scaffold it works fine. But if I place this widget in a custom Widget it doesn't change its value in display.

Comment: Are you sure the value which you are getting is different?

Comment: yes the value changes but it doesn't update the widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many limitations in this counter package. Please consider creating your own counter. It's easy and straight forward. It's better if you separate the whole counter in a different widget so that it won't build every widgets while calling `setState`. Alternatively you can use `inheritted widget` or *Provider state management*.

```
int timerSeconds;
DateTime startedAt;


StartTimer(){

_timer= new Timer.periodic(oneSec, (Timer t) => {
         
      setState(() {
        startedAt=DateTime.now();
        seconds--;
      })
    });
}
//to format the timer text
 String _printDuration(Duration duration) {
    String twoDigits(int n) {
      if (n >= 10) return "$n";
      return "0$n";
    }
    String twoDigitMinutes = twoDigits(duration.inMinutes.remainder(60));
    String twoDigitSeconds = twoDigits(duration.inSeconds.remainder(60));
    return "${twoDigits(duration.inHours)}:$twoDigitMinutes:$twoDigitSeconds";
  }

String getTimerText(){
   int timePassed= DateTime.now().difference(startedAt).inSeconds;
   timerTextString=_printDuration(Duration(seconds: timerText-timePassed));
}
```

Then stop the timer when disposing of.

```
@override
  void dispose() {
    _timer.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Then call the text string in Text widget like this

```
Text(getTimerText());
```

Comment: I got the gist of what you are trying to say thank you. I am ditching this counter to work on my my own now.

Comment: please don't forget to upvote the correct answer! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry I got so busy solving the problem I forgot about it. I used provider to solve it. Took me 3 hours lol